# 'lucid' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to use lucid architecture in Laravel, so i tried [Lucid • Microservice - Laravel](https://github.com/lucid-architecture/laravel-microservice) but I am not able to run lucid commands in the cli.

As per the document we want to set Lucid Setup. I tried to setup the Lucid but not able to run the lucid commands.

Answer (score 3):

In your console where your laravel project is installed please execute the following command:

export PATH="$PATH:./vendor/bin"